# How can I find the bandwidth of a sinc function?

Tags: bandwidth, signal-theory

I have a solved problem and it says the bandwidth of the function:

$$sinc(\frac \omega {20000}) \cdot rect(\frac \omega {20000 \pi})$$

is 10 kHz. Why it is not 20 kHz or 40 kHz ?

Comment: What equation does the solved problem give you, and where does it come from?

Comment: If w is meant to be \$\omega\$ (aka 2\$\pi f\$) then why would it be 10 kHz let alone 20 or 40?

Comment: What bandwidth? Noise equivalent, zero to zero, -3dB, -6dB, -60dB?

Comment: I think this question is about the fourier transform of the sinc function in time - it produces a rectangular spectrum that is f/2. Link: http://www.ni.com/cms/images/devzone/tut/a/31a1dcae1757.gif

Comment: You can make questions much clearer, and easier to understand by typesetting Math correctly. You can do this by enclosing your equations in "\\$" equation "\$".

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the definition of the \$\mathrm{rect}\$ function you are using, but the most likely confusion is \$\omega=2\pi{}f\$, not \$\pi{}f\$.

However, in the usual definition of \$\mathrm{rect}\$, for example [as given by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function),  the bandwidth of \$\mathrm{rect}(\frac{\omega}{20,000\pi})\$ is normally stated as 5 kHz, not 10 kHz, because we consider only the portion of the passband in the positive frequencies.